# Meaning of "9/11 is plain wrong" joke

Tags: jokes

My friend said to me that making fun out of 9/11 is plain wrong, and then he said it was a joke?

Honestly I don't get the joke? Why would it be plain wrong? Doesn't plain mean nothing? I'm confused.

Comment: *plain/plane* is a pun.

Comment: It's a very poorly implemented pun, though. "9/11 is plane wrong" might make sense in some pidgin, but it is entirely devoid of meaning in Standard English. It makes no sense to the OP because it *really* makes no sense. With or without the explanation, he is none the wiser.

Answer (score 6):

It's a pun that only makes sense when it's spoken.

> 9/11 is plain wrong.

when spoken sounds like:

> 9/11 is plane wrong.

*Plane* is short for *airplane*. I hope I don't need to explain why airplanes are significant to 9/11...

Comment: The joke itself is great. The subject, far less so (devastated many lives and cause the word to become a darker place). Having said that - shouldn't it say "*plainLY wrong*" to be correct? Is is it colloquially correct to skip the last two characters?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: "Plain ____" is colloquially used, at least in some dialects. My mother speaks that way. "The movie was just plain boring!" etc.  I don't think it's "correct," but I know better than to challenge her on such things. :)